# Eigenvalue of a linear map over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, eigenvalues

Let $ F_q $ be a finite field with $ q $ elements.
Let $ g $ be a multiplicative generator of $ F_{q^2}^* $. 
It implies that 
$ <g^{q+1}> = F_q^*  $. 
Let $ l $ be a prime greater than $ q^2-1 $ and dividing 
$  q^{2(q-1)}-1 $.

Identify $ F_l^{q+1} $ with $ R = F_l [x]/(x^{q+1}- q^{-2}) $.
Define the polynomial
$$ m(x) = \sum_{b \in g+F_q}  x^{\log_g b}  $$ in $R$.
Define two $ F_l $-linear maps on  $ R $. The first one is $ M $, which is the
multiplication by $ m(x) $   in $ R $. 
The second one is $ T $, which sends $ x^k $  to
$ x^k x^{\log_g (c)} $ where 
$ c = (g^{k(q-1)+1}-1)/(g^{q}-g) $ for $ 0\leq k < q+1 $.

It can be proved that $ 1 $ is an eigenvalue of $  M T $. 
We have verified that for many $ q $,  the eigenvalue $ 1 $  has
multiplicity $ 1 $. 
Is it true for all prime power $ q>3 $ ? Has the similar problem
been studied before?